# Language Switching doesn't occur if url is entered in French having English store currently - in magento

Tags: magento

I have difficulty that my current store is English & I am in category page but the thing is, that now if I write url's category.html part to it's french version then it gives an error of 404 page not found.

Ex. http://www.abcd.fr/r4-cards.html to http://www.abcd.fr/cartes-r4.html (From English to French View) - These are dummy urls so don't click to view!

Other thing is when I enter french url then the whole site should be converted in French view.

Any Help?

Please.

Comment: have you localized your urls ?  If not then you have the same url for both languages and language switch is done in session or by store-view code in url

Comment: Thanks Anton, for your reply. I have 2 store views that is English & French & all the products & categories have different urls in English & French but still not so now?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to rebuild indexes . if everything is set up properly this is a cache and old indexes issue

Comment: Thanks Anton, but the problem is yet not solved. Now I want to tell you how I made my site readalbe in two languages. I went to Configuration then went to manage stores at top left corner then I clicked Store View & filled for french. Is it ok or wrong?

Comment: Url is a product attribute so you should have different urls set if you want to localize this part

Comment: whichever the categories I have, all have different urls in English and French and all the products have different urls in English & French. so suppose i have a requirement of 2 categories then I have 2 in English view & 2 in French view. So now?